# Please find below code to count chars in given string. I want to know my approach is right or what is the best way?

Tags: java, string

```
public String getCharCntStr(String inputStr){
        List<Character> alreadyCntChrs=new ArrayList<>();//store already counted chars
        StringBuilder outputStr=new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0;i<inputStr.length();i++){
            char a=inputStr.charAt(i);
            if(alreadyCntChrs.contains(a)){
                continue;
            }
            int count=0;
            for(int j=i;i<inputStr.length();j++){// to find count of a char in string
                if(a==inputStr.charAt(j))
                    count++;
            }
            outputStr.append(a).append(count);
            alreadyCntChrs.add(a);
        }
        return outputStr.toString();
    }
```

example input: sanaullahshaikh
 ouput: s2a3n1u1l2h3i1k1
Please suggest me the best way to do.

Comment: Do you know what a hashmap is?

Comment: Yeah, We can create char and count key value pair. In which we have to check containsKey for every char.

Comment: The easiest way IMO would be to just iterate over every character in the string and tally using a hashmap.

Comment: I want to understand the O notation for both approach. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good but what i have implemented will give you some modifications

```
 static void characterCount(String inputString) {
        //Creating a HashMap containing char as a key and occurrences as  a value
        HashMap<Character, Integer> charCountMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        //Converting given string to char array
        char[] strArray = inputString.toCharArray();
        //checking each char of strArray
        for (char c : strArray) {
            if (charCountMap.containsKey(c)) {
                //If char is present in charCountMap, incrementing it's count by 1
                charCountMap.put(c, charCountMap.get(c) + 1);
            } else {
                //If char is not present in charCountMap,
                //putting this char to charCountMap with 1 as it's value
                charCountMap.put(c, 1);
            }
        }
        //Printing the charCountMap
        System.out.println(charCountMap);
    }
```

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: we need output as  ouput: s2a3n1u1l2h3i1k1.  Means char count should be in sequence. Can we do this by HashMap?

Answer (score 0):

Using forEach loops makes the code somewhat cleaner:

```
for (char c : input.toCharArray())
```

Using a `HashMap` makes counting repetitions `O(n)`, with n = length of string; your code is currently cuadratic `O(n^2)`. However, `HashMaps` do not guarantee any ordering. Using a `LinkedHashMap` does guarantee ordering, at a slight performance penalty, which does not affect asymptotic (big-o) performance.

Therefore, fast, `O(n)` code could be the following:

```
public static String charCountsInString(String input) {
    // count character repetitions in a hashmap that preserves ordering
    Map<Character, Integer> counts = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        counts.put(c, counts.getOrDefault(c, 0)+1);
    }

    // output characters in order, with their repetition counts
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : counts.entrySet()) {
        output.append(e.getKey()).append(e.getValue());
    }
    return output.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! for your help..  I was unaware to getOrDefault() method.